# show JSON response in html page

Tags: javascript, json

i have a php file that generate data in JSON type:

```
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    if($_POST["id"] == 1){
        $arr = array(
            'firstname' => "John",
            'lastname' => "Doe"
        );
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

i want to show response in a html page using JQuery AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://apk.vitka.ir/apk-api/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "id=1",
        success: function(data){
            var person = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(person.name);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

what is wrong in my code and how i can correct this?
then i want to show resaults in html template in page like this:

```
<div class="someclass">First Name Is : John</div>
<div class="someclass">Last Name Is : Doe</div>
```

how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
The data variable is already the parsed object and does not need to be parsed again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be a bit half-baked, but if you want the first name and last name in the HTML, you'll need containers for them:

```
<div class="someclass">First Name Is : <span id="firstName"></span></div>
<div class="someclass">Last Name Is : <span id="lastName"></span></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://apk.vitka.ir/apk-api/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "id=1",
        success: function(data){
            var person = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $('#firstName').text(person[0].firstName);
            $('#lastName').text(person[0].lastname);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this make error : "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: That should do it.